# Unit testing a Router provider in Go

Tags: unit-testing, go

I have a file in my project as :

```
package handlers

import (
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

type IHandlerProvider interface {
    GetRouter() *mux.Router
}

type HandlerProvider struct{}

func (h HandlerProvider) GetRouter() *mux.Router {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/health", Health).Methods("GET")
    return r
}
```

What is the right way to unit test this? For instance:

```
package handlers

import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

func TestGetRouterOk(t *testing.T) {
    var subject IHandlerProvider = HandlerProvider{}
    router := subject.GetRouter()
    assert.NotNil(t, router)
}
```

I can assert the object not being null, but how can I test the routes are correct?

Comment: Send requests to the mux with the [response recorder](https://godoc.org/net/http/httptest#ResponseRecorder) or the [test server](https://godoc.org/net/http/httptest#Server) and check that the response is what you expect.

Comment: This code looks a bit like Java/C# code. Testing in Go often works differently than in those languages, often much simpler: No mocks, no interfaces. Take a look at how gorilla itself writes tests for their muxer or how the mixer of the stdlib is tested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to test that the router is returning expected handler (vs test behaviour), you can do something like the following:

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.HandleFunc("/a", handlerA).Methods("GET")
r.HandleFunc("/b", handlerB).Methods("GET")

req, err := httptest.NewRequest("GET", "http://example.com/a", nil)
require.NoError(err, "create request")

m := &mux.RouteMatch{}
require.True(r.Match(req, m), "no match")

v1 := reflect.ValueOf(m.Handler)
v2 := reflect.ValueOf(handlerA)
require.Equal(v1.Pointer(), v2.Pointer(), "wrong handler")
```

Comment: Use [httptest.NewRequest](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#NewRequest) for server requests, not http.NewRequest. They are subtly different.

Comment: How do they differ?

Comment: httptest.NewRequest calls http.ReadRequest, but http.NewRequest does not. ReadRequest sets RequestURI, for instance.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [httptest](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/) package.

`handlers.go`:

```golang
package handlers

import (
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

type IHandlerProvider interface {
    GetRouter() *mux.Router
}

type HandlerProvider struct {}

func Health(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("ok"))
}

func (h HandlerProvider) GetRouter() *mux.Router {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/health", Health).Methods("GET")
    return r
}
```

`handlers_test.go`:

```golang
package handlers

import (
  "testing"
  "bytes"
  "io/ioutil"
  "net/http/httptest"
)


func TestGetRouterOk(t *testing.T) {
  assertResponseBody := func(t *testing.T, s *httptest.Server, expectedBody string) {
        resp, err := s.Client().Get(s.URL+"/health")
        if err != nil {
            t.Fatalf("unexpected error getting from server: %v", err)
        }
        if resp.StatusCode != 200 {
            t.Fatalf("expected a status code of 200, got %v", resp.StatusCode)
        }
        body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        if err != nil {
            t.Fatalf("unexpected error reading body: %v", err)
        }
        if !bytes.Equal(body, []byte(expectedBody)) {
            t.Fatalf("response should be ok, was: %q", string(body))
        }
  }
  
  var subject IHandlerProvider = HandlerProvider{}
  router := subject.GetRouter()
  s := httptest.NewServer(router)
  defer s.Close()
  assertResponseBody(t, s, "ok")
}
```

unit test result:

```
=== RUN   TestGetRouterOk
--- PASS: TestGetRouterOk (0.00s)
PASS
ok      github.com/mrdulin/golang/src/stackoverflow/64584472    0.097s
```

coverage:

[image]